# How to structure a trigger that can handle multi row insertion?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2019

I am working on SQL Server 2019

I am trying to create a trigger to audit changes on TestTable.
Here's my trigger:

```
Create TRIGGER trg_insert_TestTable on TestTable
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TestTable_change_log (update_by, update_time, operation, before_change, after_change)
    SELECT USER_NAME(), GETDATE(), 'INSERT', 'N/A' AS before_change,
        COALESCE((SELECT i.device_name + ',' + i.device_id + ',' + i.to_table_name
                  FROM inserted i
                  FOR XML PATH('')), 'N/A') AS after_change
    FROM inserted i;
END
```

However, my trigger cannot handle multi row insertion like this:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable
(device_name, device_id, to_table_name) 
VALUES
('1', '1', '1'),
('2', '2', '2'),
('3', '3', '3'),
('4', '4', '4')
```

**Output:**

```
+----------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------+----------------------+
| audit_id | update_by | update_time            | operation | before_change | after_change         |
+----------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------+----------------------+
| 1        | user      | 1/29/2024 00:00:00.000 | INSERT    | N/A           | 4,4,43,3,32,2,21,1,1 |
+----------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------+----------------------+
| 2        | user      | 1/29/2024 00:00:00.000 | INSERT    | N/A           | 4,4,43,3,32,2,21,1,1 |
+----------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------+----------------------+
| 3        | user      | 1/29/2024 00:00:00.000 | INSERT    | N/A           | 4,4,43,3,32,2,21,1,1 |
+----------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------+----------------------+
| 4        | user      | 1/29/2024 00:00:00.000 | INSERT    | N/A           | 4,4,43,3,32,2,21,1,1 |
+----------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------+----------------------+
```

**Expect: **

```
+----------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
| audit_id | update_by | update_time            | operation | before_change | after_change |
+----------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
| 1        | user      | 1/29/2024 00:00:00.000 | INSERT    | N/A           | 4,4,4        |
+----------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
| 2        | user      | 1/29/2024 00:00:00.000 | INSERT    | N/A           | 3,3,3        |
+----------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
| 3        | user      | 1/29/2024 00:00:00.000 | INSERT    | N/A           | 2,2,2        |
+----------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
| 4        | user      | 1/29/2024 00:00:00.000 | INSERT    | N/A           | 1,1,1        |
+----------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
```

Or this:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (device_name) VALUES ('dv99')
```

**Output:**

```
+----------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
| audit_id | update_by | update_time            | operation | before_change | after_change |
+----------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
| 1        | user      | 1/29/2024 00:00:00.000 | INSERT    | N/A           |              |
+----------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
```

**Expect:**

```
+----------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
| audit_id | update_by | update_time            | operation | before_change | after_change |
+----------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
| 1        | user      | 1/29/2024 00:00:00.000 | INSERT    | N/A           | dv99,N/A,N/A |
+----------+-----------+------------------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
```

Here are the related tables structure:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable_change_log ( 
    audit_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    update_by NVARCHAR(128),
    update_time DATETIME,
    operation NVARCHAR(20),
    before_change NVARCHAR(MAX),
    after_change NVARCHAR(MAX)
);


CREATE TABLE TestTable (
    device_name NVARCHAR(128),
    device_id NVARCHAR(128),
    to_table_name NVARCHAR(128)
);
```

Can someone please let me know how should I modify my trigger? I am thinking creating a temp Table and use while loop to insert every row from inserted.

Comment: Is the goal here to log all changes on your TestTable? If so you're better of just creating a slowely changing dimention type 2 or type 3 based on your TestTable. https://www.sqlshack.com/implementing-slowly-changing-dimensions-scds-in-data-warehouses/

Comment: Why the extra `SELECT` inside the `COALESCE()`? Why not just concatenate the three columns?

Comment: Why are you using `XML PATH` to concatenate data from multiple rows when you just need a simple concatenation of column values from the single row?

Comment: Thanks, a simple concatenation works for me!!!

Comment: Why not just use a temporal table? Then you don't need to write your own triggers. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear why you thought you needed the string aggregation. You can just do a normal `INSERT...SELECT...`.

Normally you would store all the columns separately, but you could use `CONCAT_WS` to store it in one column.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER trg_insert_TestTable on TestTable
AFTER INSERT
AS 

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    RETURN;  -- early bailout

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO TestTable_change_log
  (update_by, update_time, operation, before_change, after_change)
SELECT
  USER_NAME(),
  GETDATE(),
  'INSERT',
  NULL AS before_change,
  CONCAT_WS(',', i.device_name, i.device_id, i.to_table_name) AS after_change
FROM inserted i;
```

Another way of storing this information is as separate rows, by unpivoting it. This also allows you to write this as an `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` trigger

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER trg_insert_TestTable on TestTable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    RETURN;  -- early bailout

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO TestTable_change_log
    (update_by, update_time, operation, id, before_change, after_change)
SELECT
  USER_NAME(),
  GETDATE(),
  ISNULL(i.id, d.id),
  IIF(d.id IS NULL,
      'INSERT',
      IIF(i.id IS NULL, 'DELETE', 'UPDATE')
  ),
  v.before_change,
  v.after_change
FROM inserted i
FULL JOIN deleted d ON d.id = i.id
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    ('device_name', CAST(d.device_name AS sql_variant), CAST(i.device_name AS sql_variant)),
    ('device_id',   d.device_id,     i.device_id),
    ('table_name',  d.to_table_name, i.table_name)
) v(column_name, before_change, after_change)
WHERE v.before_change IS DISTINCT FROM v.after_change;
-- for older versions of SQL Server use:
-- WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT v.before_change INTERSECT SELECT v.after_change)
```

**Or just use Temporal Tables, which already do all this for you.**

On a side note: SQL Server now has `STRING_AGG` so even if you really did need aggregation you could use that.